# Cannot ping ubuntu into ubuntu via ssh

Tags: iptables

yesterday, everything on my ubuntu server 16.04 was working fine (as it did for a few years before), but all the sudden today it doesn't work anymore.

So what's not working anymore:

- I cannot ping the server anymore
- I cannot ssh (Operation timed out)

So in other words I'm stuck outside the server: I cannot ssh to the server. I went into rescue mode (from an admin panel provided by the web hosting company), and after mounting the partitions, I checked the iptable rules, which are shown below:

[image]

But as I understand them (not an expert though) the ping should have worked, and it doesn't.

Any idea what this could come from?
(I've read some other posts on this forum where people were in the same case, and it started working again suddenly the next day, but what if it doesn't?).

I contacted the web hosting company but they think the problem comes from my server configuration.

Comment: the first iptables rule for ssh jump to f2b-sshd chain, but You don't have accept for ssh in this chain before drop everything

Comment: @ling, I see you have fail2ban running. It may be that your IP is banned by fail2ban. May be you can try to ssh/ping from a different host and see if it works.

Comment: @ling, hi, could you solve your problem? Was it fail2ban? Please leave a feedback.